# Importing a 30 MB PDF file

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, import, pdf

I want to import a PDF (approximately 30 MB) and perform Georeferencing.
However, when I try to import the PDF to the "Georeferencer" my CPU usage boosts up to 100%, QGIS freezes and does not respond anymore. I have relatively modern hardware (I5 11th gen, 16 Gb RAM, IRIS XE graphics).

I am using QGIS 3.16.

Comment: Now I was able to import the PDF (after waiting for half an hour). Nonetheless, the PDF is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it would be much more performant, if you convert your PDF to TIFF first using *gdal_translate* inside OSGeo4W shell.

With transparency:

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 4 --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co ZLEVEL=9 -co PREDICTOR=2 -co TILED=YES <source.pdf> <target.tif>
```

Without transparency:

```
gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES -co JPEG_QUALITY=90 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 <source.pdf> <target.tif>
```

Afterwards you can add overlays as well:

```
gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES -r cubicspline <source.tif> 2 4 8 16
```

Comment: Can you help me a little bit with that? I never used the shell so far, only R. How do I specify my directory?

Comment: @Kevin_S2021 maybe this can help: https://cdn.tutsplus.com/webdesign/uploads/2013/07/OSGEO4W-what-to-type-in-at-the-command-prompt.pdf